# Kogito - wait until data from multiple endpoints is received

Tags: drools, quarkus, bpmn, kogito

I am using Kogito with Quarkus. I have set on drl rule and am using a bpmn configuration. As can be seen below, currently one endpoint is exposed, that starts the process. All needed data is received from the initial request, it is then evaluated and process goes on.

I would like to extend the workflow to have two separate endpoints. One to provide the age of the person and another to provide the name. The process must wait until all needed data is gathered before it proceeds with evaluation.

Has anybody come across a similar solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could use a signal or message to add more data into a process instance before you execute the rules over the entire data, see https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#ref-bpmn-intermediate-events_kogito-developing-process-services.
In order to do that you need to have some sort of correlation between these events, otherwise, how do you map that event name 1 should be matched to event age 1. If you can keep the process instance id, then the second event can either trigger a rest endpoint to the specific process instance or send it a message via a message broker.
You also have your own custom logic to aggregate the events and only fire a new process instance once your criteria of complete data is met, and there is also plans in Kogito to extend the capabilities of how correlation is done, allowing for instance to use variables of the process as the identifier. For example, if you have person.id as correlation and event to name and age of the same id would signal the same process instance. HOpe this info helps.